# Genymotion failed to flash open_gapps-x86_64-7.0-stock-20170208.zip archieve

Tags: android, genymotion

Hi I have added `Google Nexus 6P 7.0` in my genymotion, it is running fine. I want to install `Google Apps` on same simulator.

I am trying to download `Google Apps` from here http://opengapps.org/ When I am trying to install this then getting an error.

Can anyone help me how to resolve this issue. Thanks in advance.

> Genymotion failed to flash open_gapps-x86_64-7.0-stock-20170208.zip archieve

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to download the `x86` version instead of the 64 Bit.

Edit: See the official documentation [here](https://www.genymotion.com/help/desktop/faq/#google-play-services).

Comment: how can I know what platform it is.. ARM/ARM64/X86/X86_64 so i can download correct version

Comment: The official documentations states that you should use the x86 version. I've edited my answer and added a link to it. Genymotion always uses the x86. It's not compatible with any Arm architecture (see docs some pages below the linked part).

Answer (score 0):

This version of Open GApps is known to work on Android 7.0 with Genymotion 2.8.1: https://github.com/opengapps/x86/releases/download/20161111/open_gapps-x86-7.0-pico-20161111.zip.

If it fails, you may need to recreate a fresh device.